# Izotope RX3 Workflow to improve audio quality

Tags: izotope, production-audio

I'm using Izotope RX3 Advanced.

I have an audio file that was recorded using a cheap wireless mic and the sound of this file reminds me of listening to it though a telephone or something on an AM radio station.

I also have spend many hours looking on a detailed tutorial or workflow that other people have done to get the audio quality to a decent level kink of like what you would hear on an FM radio station. All I found was "you can this" or "I can do that" etc. and they even have before and after sound clips that proove it can be done. They don't let out the secret. It's so frustrating. All I want is to know "how" they did it.

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you necessarily need RX - sounds like EQ is going to be a more effective tool. RX is used to remove noise and fix specific issues:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4dISychPQEt04pe2EFaPRHe_477PZWdW

Mike Thornton's vids give you a good overview. They actually show you it step by step too.

If your sound is all midrange then EQ to add highs and lows. To do this effectively you need trained ears more than anything. If it's distorted Izotope may help, but not in every case. Difficult to gauge without actually hearing it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to use RX to remove the noise. I will look at the video you posted a link to see if that will help me. I hope it has a step by step tutorial on using the RX equalizer.

Comment: I checked the videos on the link but no tutorials for the RX equalizer. Does anyone know of any?

Comment: Search for 'using EQ on dialog', there is some stuff out there, and even some on SE. Izotope EQ is not dissimilar from all the other EQ's out there.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the reply. There are a lot of YouTube videos that I found on that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Every audio file is different so what works on 1 might not work on the other.  What about it reminds you of a telephone? frequency spectrum, EQ, distortion?
Depending on the issue you might need RX but other tools might help you out more.  Its a very deep set of tools.  How much have you tried?  Have you read through the Izotope Noise reduction guide, some very good tips in there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I did go through the manual but I was hoping for a workflow to give me an idea on how to do it. The files sounds thin and somewhat tinny, kind of like listening to a talk show on an AM radio station. I'm looking to make the file sounds like the quality you would hear on an FM radio station.

Comment: Multiband compression/expansion, maybe some EQ are probably more what I would use in this situation.